# jquery ajax: shortform for $(this).attr('data-ajax-link')?

Tags: jquery, ajax, short

I've heard there is a better way to query the "data-ajax-link" attribute of some element.

I'm using this right now: 
`$(this).attr('data-ajax-link')`

What's the shortform of this? Googled it quickly but couldn't find the answer.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here it is](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/):

```
$(this).data('ajax-link')
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
$(this).data('ajax-link');
```

Note that it will only work on jQuery 1.4.3 and above. Quote:

> As of jQuery 1.4.3 HTML 5 data- attributes will be automatically pulled in to jQuery's data object. The treatment of attributes with embedded dashes was changed in jQuery 1.6 to conform to the W3C HTML5 specification.

Taken from **http://api.jquery.com/data/**